# Searching in string for a substring

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, substring

Hey guys I do have the following code for searching for substring in a file of around 700 thousands letters I believe , it works fine for ArrayList but for LinkedList it takes forever to finish. anyone can see why it takes all that time? =S

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountSubstrings {
    private static int sumAL=0;
    private static int sumLL=0;
    private static List<Character> sAList= new ArrayList<Character>();
    private static List<Character> sLList= new LinkedList<Character>();
    private static List<Character> pattAL= new ArrayList<Character>();
    private static List<Character> pattLL= new LinkedList<Character>();
    private static int index=0;
    private static double timer=0;
    private static double Otimer=0;

    /*
     * Returns the lowest index at which substring pattern begins in text (or
     * else -1).
     */

    private static int findBrute(List<Character> text, List<Character> pattern,  int position) {
        int n = text.size();
        int m = pattern.size();
        for (int i = position; i <= n - m; i++) { // try every starting index 
                                 // within text
            int k = 0; // k is index into pattern
            while (k < m && (text.get(i + k) == pattern.get(k)))
            {   // kth character of pattern matches
                k++;
                if (k == m )
                {   index=i;
                    return i;} // substring text[i..i+m-1] is a match
                }
            }

        return -1; // search failed
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the path for the input file: ");
        String fileName= sc1.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the pattern to look for: ");
        String subString= sc2.next();

        for(char c: subString.toCharArray())
        {
            pattAL.add(c);
            pattLL.add(c);
        }

        System.out.println("current time "+System.currentTimeMillis()+" milliseconds");
        try (BufferedReader OpenFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)))
        {
            // file is opened here and we can access everything in there.
            String sSLine;
            String content = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            //System.out.println(content);

     // find int answer line by line not complete

            while ((sSLine = OpenFile.readLine()) != null) {
                sSLine.replace('\n', ',');// making sure we add every word alone even when we encounter \n
                for(char c: sSLine.toCharArray())
                {
                    sAList.add(c);
                    sLList.add(c);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //Array List by pointer

        //starting ARRAY LIST
        Otimer=System.currentTimeMillis();
         while(findBrute(sAList,pattAL,index)!=-1)
         {
                index=index+pattAL.size();
                sumAL++;
         }

         timer=System.currentTimeMillis()-Otimer;
         Otimer=System.currentTimeMillis();
         index=0; // resetting the index  OR  we can make 2 other variables indexAL  indexLL  if magic numbers were so bad
         System.out.println("Using ArrayList: "+sumAL+" matches, derived in "+timer+ " milliseconds");
         while(findBrute(sLList,pattLL,index)!=-1)
         {
            System.out.println("index"+index+" char: "+sLList.get(index));

            index=index+pattLL.size();
            //if(sLList.get(index))
            sumLL++;
            System.out.println("index"+index+" char: "+sLList.get(index+1));
         }
         timer=System.currentTimeMillis()-Otimer;
    System.out.println("Using Linked List: matches "+sumLL+" time, derived in "+timer+ " milliseconds");
      }
}
```

Comment: You might start by getting rid of `sSLine.replace('\n', ',');` - it does not do anything!

Comment: ahh that is true , but the Linked List takes forever @_@

Comment: I believe it is linked list pointer issue....    (.next) but i am not so good with that

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand how a [Linked list](http://Linked%20list) work. Every item in a Linked list reference the next item in the list (and in Java's case, also the previous). Because of this, to get the item at a specific index in a Linked list, it is necessary to *traverse all items* from either end of the list, until you arrive at the right index. 
In comparison, an `ArrayList` is built upon an array and therefore allows very quick access to arbitrary indexes.

Let's look at the documentation for [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. **Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end**, whichever is closer to the specified index.

And for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The size, isEmpty, **get**, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in **constant time**.

In your code you use the `get` method within a loop in your `findBrute` method.

```
...                    ↓                     ↓
while (k < m && (text.get(i + k) == pattern.get(k)))
...
```

And also in your `while` loop in the `main` method:

```
...                                                ↓
System.out.println("index"+index+" char: "+sLList.get(index));
...
```

So, because of the way Linked Lists work, this code will take more time with a Linked List compared to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I see , so i should minimize the .get for Linked list as much as possible?

Comment: That would be a good idea. Or just use the appropriate list (i.e. `ArrayList`). Linked lists are not really designed for accessing arbitrary indexes.

Comment: if I am not going to use . get for Linked List then I should make loop with updating the node pointer?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. By iterating through the Linked List and maintaining a reference to the current item, you should be able to eliminate a lot of iterations caused by `get`.

Comment: ahhh , i see! that sounds fun to look for =D  . thanks

Comment: @ahmad Is there are finalized answer for this.